# Create New User on ADFS by running remote powershell comand

Tags: powershell, adfs

I have a problem in communication between two hosts, in details, I have two hosts in LAN.

1) **[A] 192.168.1.10:** On this host I have Windows Server 2012 R2
2) **[B] 192.168.1.12:** On this host I have Windows Server 2003 with ADFS installed.

My problem is:
I have to add a new user on ADFS by running powershell script on first host ( 192.168.1.10 ).

I tried this solution:

On host **A** I Execute current powershell script, for running powershell remote commands:

```
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String <mypassword>
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\User",$pw
$session = Enter-PSSession -computername 192.168.1.12 -credential $cred
```

This instantiates a remote connection with host **B** which has ADFS.

On host **B** I have a script **"CreateADUser.ps1"** that add a new record on ADFS. But I don't like this solution.

Can I connect directy ADFS on host B by host A?
What function When I have more request on A host?

Important information:
to need I can't using directly **B** host, but I have to pass from **A** host.

What is your solution?

Comment: I have to have a windows service on host A, that communicate with host B. This service must always be listening on host A. When I execute service.bat I'm actually launching commands on the host B.

Comment: ADFS has no concept of users. Are you trying to add a user to AD? Or what are you trying to do with ADFS?

Comment: I'm trying to add user on ADFS. I have both hosts on the same network... but ADFS is on host B(with Windows Server 2003) and before to go on host B I have to pass(mandatory) by host A(with Windows Server 2012 R2)..this is my issue. I would to use powershell to add user on ADFS.

Comment: Some confusion here. You can only add RP and CP to ADFS not users. Not really relevant in the context of the question - just curious.

Comment: Yes, I belive that not is relevant. I would focus on hosts comunication.
On how execute batch file on host A executing  powershell script on host B...